# Get records by Id method using DbContext in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Here, in Asp.Net, normal webforms,  I'm using dependency injection for retrieving records. I have also used Entity Framework here

I have a class and a interface shown below..

```
public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {

        }

        public Student StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

public interface IStudentService
    {
        Student GetStudentsById(Student StudentID);
        IList<Student> GetAllStudents();
    }
```

created a context class

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

then implemented the interface

```
public partial class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();

        public virtual Student GetStudentsById(Student StudentID)
        {
            //need to implement
        }    

        public virtual IList<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
            //need to implement
        }    
    }
```

Now, could anyone help me to implement these methods

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `public Student StudentID` is supposed to be `public int StudentID`:

```
public partial class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    public virtual Student GetStudentById(int studentId)
    {
        return db.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == studentId);
    }

    public virtual IList<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return db.Students.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get Student records into a List by passing StudentId

Comment: @user1469330 I assume all students have a unique ID therefore why would you want to return a list with a single item in it?